# Bash Script - String Split Paragraph Into Sentences

Tags: string, git, bash, split

I'm trying to write a prepare-commit-msg git hook script to check the contents of the last 10 commit messages and check to see if the message that you are attempting to enter is unique and prevent the user from checking in (without the --no-verify overload) if it detects it.  When I run this command line in Git I get the following output.

```
    dacke@MachineName /c/Development/Project (tests)
    $ git log --pretty=format:'%h|%an|%s' --max-count=10
    2919dc2|Eric|Test Message
    4ef580c|Eric|Test Message
    1a0051b|Eric|Test Message
    3e2df42|Eric|Test Commit
    a08d4c1|Bob|DE6717 - What I did to fix this defect
    aff8afc|Bob|DE6717 - Here is some more defect info
    bbbfb67|Ralph|Merge branch 'clean_up' into develop
    72d0968|Ralph|Forgot to remove deleted class from the project.
    bfd1505|Ralph|Clean up.
    d21c6dc|Bruce|Merge branch 'Icons' into develop
```

My prepare-commit-msg is written like so.

```
1   #!/bin/bash
2
3   printf "Prepare-Commit-Msg Hook Running...\n"
4
5   #$1 = "Commit Message File 'COMMIT_EDITMSG'"
6   #$2 = "message"
7   commitMessage=$(cat "$1")
8  
9   #    Prevent people putting in the same commit message multiple times by looking for an identical message in the last 10 commits
10  declare -a last10CommitMessages
11  rawMessages=$(git log --pretty=format:'%h|%an|%s«' --max-count=10)
12  printf "Raw Messages Length: %d\n" "${#rawMessages[@]}"
13  for line in ${rawMessages//«/ };
14  do 
15  #printf "%s\n" $line
16  last10CommitMessages+=($line);
17  done
18  printf "Last 10 Commit Length: %d\n" "${#last10CommitMessages[@]}"
19 
20  # Temp exit 1 to prevent commit during testing
21  exit 1
```

When I try to run the "commit" I get the following output.
Raw Messages Length: 1
Last 10 Commit Length: 63

If I uncomment line 15 I can see that for every space and line break I'm getting an item added to the array.  On top of that the character that I actually wanted to split the lines on is added to the end which means that I would need yet another method to take this off the end.

I am new to bash scripting and I'm coming from a C# / Windows background so I still learning.  Can someone please provide me a simple solution to the problem?  More important to me than a quick answer is an answer that can explain HOW this actually works.  I've found a lot of conflicting information that does not work for me on the web.  I plan on writing a blog piece about this after I get it all figured out so it's important that I don't get any "It just works" as an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change 
`rawMessages=$(git log --pretty=format:'%h|%an|%s«' --max-count=10)`

to this

`rawMessages=($(git log --pretty=format:'%h|%an|%s«' --max-count=10))`

$( ) evaluates the command inside and saves it as one string, ignoring line breaks. When you wrap something with ( ), it evaluates the contents as an array.

EDIT:

If you do this you will see you have way more elements in the array than you wanted. This is because the array will split the string by new line character and white space. To ignore white space you can do as hlovdal suggested and do this..

```
OLD_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'

rawMessages=($(git log --pretty=format:'%h|%an|%s«' --max-count=10))

IFS="$OLD_IFS"
```

Answer (score 1):

The words are split due to the `IFS` variable (Internal Field Separator - an ancient unix relic...) which has default value `"<space><tab><newline>"`. Change your loop to

```
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=«
for line in ${rawMessages}
do
        printf "%s\n" $line
        last10CommitMessages+=($line);
done
IFS=$oldIFS
```